# Google maps v3 API - calculate bounds given center coordinates and distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I've seen [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774579/calculate-bounds-from-center-and-zoom-google-maps-api-v3) on how to calculate bounds given center and zoom, but I'm trying to calculate bounds given center coordinates and a distance in miles.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [computeOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance) to calculate a point at a distance east and west of the center.  Add those two points to a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) and call map.fitBounds on that bounds.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ntv4gqu6/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Geometry library. Include the libraries=geometry
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 37.04831, lng: -95.297565}
  });
  var distance = 10000; // 10 km
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var east = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), distance, 90);
  bounds.extend(east);
  var west = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), distance, 270);
  bounds.extend(west);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [east, west],
    map: map
  });
  var lineLength = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(polyline.getPath());
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  infowindow.setContent("line length is "+(lineLength/1000).toFixed(2)+" km");
  infowindow.setPosition(map.getCenter());
  infowindow.open(map);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```