# How to convert Position and Zoom Level to LatLngBounds with Google Maps Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I start to implement a web solution to display a GroundOverlay on a google maps.
With IOS and Android, it's possible to add a GroundOverlay, with the center, image and zoom level but it's not possible in Javascript.

- Javascript : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#GroundOverlay.constructor
- IOS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_ground_overlay#a894dab44f5fb3f7e5c45431f3e7ab513

So what is the mathematical solution to convert a **position** (Lat, Lng) to a **bound** ((Lat,Lng),(Lat,Lng))?

Here is what I have:

- Center Position (Latitude, Longitude)
- ImageUrl
- ZoomLevel
- Google Map

Comment: You don't have enough information to compute the bounds in your question. If you want the GroundOverlay to fill the bounds of the map, you can get those from the zoom level and center (the returned value will depend on the size and shape of the `map` div)

Comment: you are true, I added the google map in what I have.

Comment: @geocodezip i'm looking for this. Do you have any idea how can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution mostly inspired from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774579/calculate-bounds-from-center-and-zoom-google-maps-api-v3/4092928#4092928).

```
function getImageDimensions(imageUrl: string): Observable<{ width: number, height: number }> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = function (event) {
      let loadedImage: any = event.currentTarget;
      observer.next({
        width: loadedImage.width,
        height: loadedImage.height
      });
      observer.complete();
    }
    image.src = imageUrl;
  });
} 



getImageDimensions(imageUrl: string, zoomLevel:number, center: google.maps.LatLng, map: google.maps.Map).subscribe(dimensions => {
  let projection = map.getProjection();
  let zoom = Math.pow(2, zoomLevel) * 2;
  let width = dimensions.width / zoom;
  let height = dimensions.height / zoom;
  let containerPixel = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(center);

  var result = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    projection.fromPointToLatLng(
      new google.maps.Point(containerPixel.x - width, containerPixel.y + height)
    ),
    projection.fromPointToLatLng(
      new google.maps.Point(containerPixel.x + width, containerPixel.y - height)
    )
  );
  console.log(result);
});
```